# how hide and show <tr> table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table that I want to show and hide some  use jquery, but it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#a").hide();
        $("#b").show();

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table ">  
        <tbody>
              <div id="a">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row"> name </th>
                        <td>
                         <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name"  required autocomplete="name" autofocus>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row"> email </th>
                        <td>
                            <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email"  required autocomplete="email" autofocus>      
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               </div>
               <div id="b">
                  <tr>
                   <th scope="row"> Adress </th>
                   <td>
                     <input id="adressem" type="text" class="form-control @error('adressem') is-invalid @enderror" name="adressem"  required autocomplete="adressem" autofocus>     
                   </td>
                  </tr>
               </div>    
                   <tr>
                     <td>
                      <div class="pull-right">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="modifier">modifier</button>
                      </div>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: You have invalid html .You cannot use `div` like that inside your table .Instead , alternative way would be giving `class="a"` to `<tr>` which you need to hide and `class="b"` to `<tr>` which you need to show .Then , in your jquery code simply write `$(".a").hide(); $(".b").show();`